# Comparing arrays for "similarity"?

Tags: algorithm, dataset

I am trying to compare same size arrays.

Given the following array:

[image]

I am looking for an algorithm to tell me the most "similar" array to the input. I understand that the word "similar" is not very specific but I don't know how to be more specific.

For example the following is very similar to the input.

[image]

The following is somewhat similar.

[image]

The following is very different.

[image]

Comment: At some point in your project you'll have to define what "similar" actually means. Is it the number of peaks? Is it the location of the peaks? Is it the average value? Is it the smoothness of the curve? There are any number of possible criteria. As long as you're not sure about this, there's not much point in discussing code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could apply a smoothing kernel to the array, and then compute the L2 norm (Euclidean distance) on it.

This is often used to compare e.g. neural spike trains or other continuous signals.

http://www.cs.utah.edu/~suresh/papers/kerneld/kerneld.pdf

You didn't specify a language...I happen to have code in C++ (may not be the most efficient).

First, you do a smoothing of the vector based on your desired kernel width and parameterize it depending on the scale/desired amount of "blur", etc.. For example:

Output of code below (behaves as expected):

```
riveale@rv-mba:~/tmpdir$ g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp -o test.exe
riveale@rv-mba:~/tmpdir$ ./test.exe
Distance [1] to [2]: [31.488026] (should be far)
Distance [2] to [3]: [26.591297] (should be far)
Distance [1] to [3]: [12.468342] (should be closer)
```

And code (test.cpp):

```
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cmath>

double gauss_kernel_funct(const size_t& sourcetime, const size_t& thistime)
{
  const double tauval = 5.0; //width of kernel

  double dist = ((sourcetime-thistime)/tauval); //distance between the points in the vector
  double retval = exp(-1 * dist*dist); //exponential decay away from center of that point, squared....
  return retval;
}

std::vector<double> convolvegauss( const std::vector<double>& v1)
{
  std::vector<double> convolved( v1.size(), 0.0 );
  for(size_t t=0; t<v1.size(); ++t)
    {
      for(size_t u=0; u<v1.size(); ++u)
      {
        double coeff = gauss_kernel_funct(u, t);
        convolved[t]+=v1[u] * coeff;
      }
    }
  return (convolved);
}

double eucliddist( const std::vector<double>& v1, const std::vector<double>& v2 )
{
  if(v1.size() != v2.size()) { fprintf(stderr, "ERROR v1!=v2 sizes\n"); exit(1); }
  double sum=0.0;
  for(size_t x=0; x<v1.size(); ++x)
    {
      double tmp = (v1[x] - v2[x]);
      sum += tmp*tmp; //sum += distance of this dimension squared
    }
  return (sqrt( sum ));
}

double vectdist( const std::vector<double>& v1, const std::vector<double>& v2 )
{
   std::vector<double> convolved1 = convolvegauss( v1 );
   std::vector<double> convolved2 = convolvegauss( v2 );
   return (eucliddist( convolved1, convolved2 ));
}

int main()
{

  //Original 3 vectors. (1 and 3) are closer than (1 and 2) or (2 and 3)...like your example.
  std::vector<double> myvector1 = {1.0, 32.0, 10.0,  5.0, 2.0};
  std::vector<double> myvector2 = {2.0,  3.0, 10.0, 22.0, 2.0};
  std::vector<double> myvector3 = {2.0, 20.0, 17.0,  1.0, 2.0};


  //Now run the vectdist on each, which convolves each vector with the gaussian kernel, and takes the euclid distance between the convovled vectors)
  fprintf(stdout, "Distance [%d] to [%d]: [%lf] (should be far)\n", 1, 2, vectdist(myvector1, myvector2) );
  fprintf(stdout, "Distance [%d] to [%d]: [%lf] (should be far)\n", 2, 3, vectdist(myvector2, myvector3) );
  fprintf(stdout, "Distance [%d] to [%d]: [%lf] (should be closer)\n", 1, 3, vectdist(myvector1, myvector3) );
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Depending on what "features" of the vector you care about you may want to do some pre-processing. For example, if you only care about the "shape", and don't care about scale, you could normalize all the vectors internally beforehand.